# Where do I put the Authentication Filter for Spring Boot 1.3.3

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cors

So I know what the problem is, I just don't know how to fix it.

## Problem

I am using Spring Boot 1.3.3 and the CorsFilter is set like the following

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private Environment env;

        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://192.168.1.132:8100")
                    .allowedHeaders("Accept", "Content-Type","X-Auth-Token", "Origin", "Pragma","Cache-Control",
                            "If-Modified-Since","Authorization")
                    .exposedHeaders("X-Auth-Token")
                    .allowedMethods("PUT","POST","GET","OPTIONS")
                    .allowCredentials(true).maxAge(3600);
        }
    }
```

## Secuity Config

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/save-user","/test","/error","/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();

        http.addFilterAfter(new CustomStatelessAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
...
    }
```

The problem I am having is that I am using a Custom Token something like `X-Auth-Token` to validate the user. BUT `CustomStatelessAuthenticationFilter` is being called before the CorsRegistry. Before Chrome makes a call it does a `OPTIONS` call to make sure the application is legit. It won't allow me to pass the `X-AUTH-TOKEN` header without validating the call is legit. So it does not allow me to pass the `X-AUTH-TOKEN` until the server gets a response status `OK` From the server. Well since the `CustomStatelessAuthenticationFilter` gets call first, the `X-AUTH-TOKEN` returns as null. To fix this I had to do something like this...

## CustomStatelessAuthenticationFilter

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    boolean debug = this.logger.isDebugEnabled();
    if(debug) {
        this.logger.debug("Custom.Custom Stateless Authentication");
    }
    if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://192.168.1.132:8100");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Auth-Token");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Auth-Token");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } else {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                this.tokenAuthenticationService.getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) request));
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

In other words I have to return to the client that Status is `OK` manually before it will make the real request. It makes two request, one to make sure the OPTION call returns a OK (Pre Flight Request), then it makes another that actually makes the call with the `X-Auth-Token` in it. I don't want to do this because its completely ignoring my CorsMapping. I want it to check the CorsMapping First before continuing on. So where do I setup the authenitcation correctly so it already accepts the `OPTIONS` check first before actually authenticating.

I've also tried something like the following in my security config

```
http.addFilterAfter(new CustomStatelessAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService),
        CsrfFilter.class);
```

I advise a Upvote for this because I have not found a solid solution. So far the `addCorsMappings` has cause me more of a pain than the older solution of just adding a `CorsFilter` in older versions

Comment: Im having the same issue. Thanks for the workarround but Did you correctly solve this. The Documentation says its possible but has no example of how to actually do it